# Any cydia App for choosing specific proxy country?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, proxy, tor

Like for those tv apps, in my case, from Spain which will only show certain content if you have a Spanish ip.
For me in Germany I thus need some kind of proxy from Spain. Does such an app exist in cydia? Or would there be any other way in order to appear as a Spanish client to the servers of that tv app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-Cydia solution. I hope it still applies as answer for your question though.

Maybe you would like to try an app called [VyprVPN](http://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn/mobile/vyprvpn-for-ios). It lets you choose your server location basically with a single button. It advertises on its Website as a "security measure", but this [review](http://vpncreative.net/vpn-providers/vyprvpn/) states

> VyprVPN can be used to bypass website restrictions or bans implemented by certain countries.

I have not tested this app myself, so I cannot "recommend" it as such, but I think based on the information provided it should to the job for you. Good luck!

Comment: thx! I always thought I would need Cydia for these kind of things, but that app looks great without any need of cydia. I might try the test version. thx for your answer!